# xml Layout Stretch in Device,

Tags: android, android-layout

I have complete layout in 480*800. In Emulator,  i run it and show prefect places but in to the device doesnot showing prefect.

Like:

```
 T       Q        N
----    ----     ----
```

**IN case EMulator:** Nothing Error, Above layout shows prefect:

**IN case of Devices:** Last N , half part not showing.

How to remove this problem in devices.

Thanks in Advance;

Comment: please post your layout xml file

Comment: Also post the screen shots if possible

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of them?

Comment: I have a cheaper "Trio" device, and it doesn't display the edges of the view due to poor quality of workmanship.  Are you sure that its not your device that is messed up?